# Failing to import generated ics file to google calendar and outlook

Tags: calendar, google-calendar-api

I'm trying to generate ics-files, see sample here: http://deap.nu/myprogram.ics

It validates alright here: https://icalendar.org/validator.html
but when trying to import it into a google calendar I get the message

"Failed to import events: Unable to process your ical/CSV file."

which isn't very informative. I've tried to slim the file down, and googled a lot but can't find whats wrong. Any input on this is appreciated.

Importing to outlook doesn't work either.

Comment: In case others find it helpful, here is another validator service that is free and available at the time of writing: https://icalendar.org/validator.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some sleep and more trial and error I managed to pinpoint the problem to the Organizer elements in the .ics file. So I removed them for now, adding the information to the description instead.

Answer (score 4):

I realize this is an old post, but I'm adding this in to help others that might run into issues trying to import an .ics file.

As far as Google Calendar, the errors are not descriptive or outright misleading.  I had a permissions error, but that was due to a UID (Unique Event ID) being in the file.  As described below from [Google's Calendar Community Forum](https://support.google.com/calendar/thread/26052664?hl=en), the solution was to remove that line from the file, save it, then try to import it again.  It worked!

> some of Google Calendar's error messages are not to be taken at face
> value... this particular error often means that your UIDs (unique
> event IDs) are not formatted to Google Calendar's liking, so my
> question is where was this ics file generated?
>
> I would try opening the file in a good text editor, and deleting every
> line starting with UID as they are not needed for inserting new
> events, and will cause this error if not formatted correctly.

Answer (score 1):

I have another recommandation for a successful import to GCalendar (calendar.google.com). I failed several times to import an ics-File with meaningless error messages.

I tried anything to make the ics-file standard conform, left out all UID rows etc. but nothing helped.

I used Google Chrome, which is my normal every day browser.
I thought: Which browser could be better to use it with Google-Services?

But: When I logged in to google-calendar using Microsoft Edge (Chromium-based) the ics-import just worked out of the box.

Hope it helps others with the same problem...
Then

Comment: This did it for me. I added the file via Firefox instead of Chrome and it worked. Really odd, but thanks for the fix @jreichert

Answer (score 0):

I just got past a problem with the same description. I could leave Organizer in, but, editing the file with emacs on linux, I noticed that the Description contained carriage returns (^M), whereas the other line breaks had been normalized to linux standard when I had saved the .ics file.  I removed the ^Ms and it then imported fine.